# First row of data grid is showing up when changing value

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datagridview, datatable

So im getting some very strange behaviour. 
I have list of books which is populated via database and it is in datatable .
i set datagridview datasource to be that datatable. 
Now i want to check if there is duplicate books , to count how many books with same name exist, and write that number in first book row, and hide others.
Same for every book in datagridview row.

**it is done nicely, but at the end, a first row of datagrid "jump" to screen and becomes visible again**. 
Here is code
 (Note: Not all books are visible when this code executes-thats why im checking row visible)

```
for (int m = 0; m < dataGridView.RowCount; m++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[m].Visible)
            {

                string name = dataGridView.Rows[m].Cells["j_name"].Value.ToString();


                int pom_count = 1;
                for (int j = m + 1; j < dataGridView.RowCount; j++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView.Rows[j].Visible)

                    {



                        string name2 = dataGridView.Rows[j].Cells["j_name"].Value.ToString();
                        //MessageBox.Show(name2);
                        if (name2 == name)
                        {
                            pom_count++;
                            dataGridView.Rows[j].Visible = false;

                        }

                    }
                }



                 dataGridView.Rows[m].Cells["repeat_number"].Value = pom_count;
            }



        }
```

So anybody knows why it happens?

Comment: The code you've shown looks OK but I am not sure what you mean by "first row of datagrid jump to screen".

Comment: @JeffR. It means , for example im having 20 rows of books displayed, and i call this method. And after execution of this method, distinct records have been removed, but also, datagridrow.rows[0] is now my first visible row, and it have not been before execution of this method- it was invisible

Comment: Do you have any events in the code.  I think an event may cause the row to become visible.

Comment: @jdweng no i dont have any events

Comment: Would it be easier to modify the DB query to just get a COUNT() of books and show that right away in the DataGridView? Have the DB do the work of aggregation?

Comment: @HardCode yes i could do that easily but im interested about this bug, why it happens

Comment: I had DataTable as datagridSource , and when i removed it and populate manualy, it works ... Strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had DataTable as datagridSource , and when i removed it and populate manualy, it works .

Anyone knows why?